# how to edit .ex4 MQL4 executable file?

Tags: mql4

Anyone tell me how can I comment out some of the line of the code from existing .ex4 (MQL4 language) file ?. I know people are doing but just don't know how to do it. I would really appreciate if someone tell me what tool I need and procedure to go about making it happen. Note: I am not looking for decompile entire code. I just want to add some line and comment some line to ex4 executable file.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot edit a ex4 file without decompiling/recompiling. If you can get the source mq4 file, then you could edit it and compile to a valid ex4 with MetaEditor.